# Visual Studio 2017 - How to disable .ASPX new {element name} Tasks: format element pop-up box

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, editor

Environment: Visual Studio 2017 15.9.4 (just noticed this recently), designing an ASP.NET 4.61 .aspx web-page.

Microsoft has added another Editor 'helper'.  On an .aspx page, When you hover over any defined HTML tag (div, table, td, span, img...etc.), you now get a white box with a > inside - like this:

[image]

I am finding it extremely trouble-some, to the point of interfering with changing aspx page content. I.e. I'll try and click the element inside, i.e. the div in `<div>` to change it to a `<p>` or `<span>` or maybe I missed, and wanted the div in the next row down - like:
[image]

As shown in the image - kind of hard to click the div now, as it is now blocked by the box - I now have to click again somewhere else to remove focus on the span element, then click again on the div. Sometimes I'll try and click around it but VS will open the box blocking and disrupting my click and show the info box:

[image: Hover over a DIV - new MS Pop-up]

I have no idea how or if it is even possible to disable this pop-up 'helper'. I do not want to loose other autocomplete, intellisense, or mouse-over info - all are helpful, just this one annoying helper...

**Does anyone here know how to turn off this element - Tasks helper?**

MS Suggestion (if anyone from MS is reading this} - I would suggest on mouse-over of a known element: auto change the background to a color indicating a known pop-up info 'available element', at which point a user could press a key-combo to show the {element} Tasks box.